# What should I know about remote shutter-releases for a Panasonic GF-1?

Tags: micro-four-thirds, triggers

I've looked around quite a bit and I'm about to bite the bullet and order the [Panasonic DMW-RSL1 Remote Shutter Release](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GBVA34) which feels quite overpriced, but is the manufacturer's own product. At that price point, I'm quite tempted to go for a slightly more featureful StudioHut product with a built-in intervalometer. Although part of me is thinking that this is ridiculous and I should just get the cheapest compatible switch I can find.

Is there any reason to prefer the manufacturer's product? Are there wireless shutter-release solutions that work with the Panasonic interface?

Comment: +1, I'm also interested especially in the wireless solutions.

Comment: I've removed the Amazon affiliate link in your question and replaced it with a non-affiliate link.  See this on meta for the community's stance on affiliate links: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/661/is-it-appropriate-for-answer-ers-to-embed-affiliate-referral-codes-into-answers

Answer (score 3):

The primary reason to go with the manufacturer's product is 100% compatibility. With 3rd party/other vendors, you need to be sure of the correct model (especially as the Panasonic supports a different, 4 pin connector - others use 2/3 pins IIRC).

There are quite a few which work though, and are marked compatible with the DMW-RSL1. If you're really in need of the better features of the studioHut, then check the compatibility and go ahead (I checked the site, and it looks like it will)

Answer (score 0):

I recently a Rainbow Imaging wireless remote that works well on a GF1. I have not tried all the interval programming yet.

[http://www.amazon.com/RainbowImaging-Panasonic-DMC-FZ50K-DMC-FZ30S-DMC-FZ30K/dp/B003TE34U2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003TE34U2)